# Is there any way to run Rspec tests on a single Ruby file?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to run some tests on some code kata exercises that I am working on. Is it possible to run Rspec tests on a single Ruby file? I tried adding `require 'rspec'` to the top of the file and then the command `rsepc` from the project dir but the following is returned:

```
F

Failures:

  1) Sentence reverser reverses the words in a sentence
     Failure/Error: expect(sentence_reverser(test_sentence)).to eq('I am backwards')

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sentence_reverser' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::SentenceReverser:0x0000559764dc5950>
```

The code I have is:

```
require 'rspec'

def sentence_reverser str
  str.split.reverse.join(' ')
end

describe "Sentence reverser" do
  it 'reverses the words in a sentence' do
    test_sentence = "backwards am I"
    expect(sentence_reverser(test_sentence)).to eq('I am backwards')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `rspec </path/to/kata.rb>`. You shouldn't even `require 'rspec'` then - just tested your example.

Comment: I'm in the directory of the file and I'm running `rspec file.rb` and it returns `Failure/Error: return gem_original_require(path) LoadError:cannot load such file -- rspec`

Comment: Ah, you're right! When I delete `require 'rspec'` it works. Thanks a lot!